# Transform Scala Future into CompletableFuture

Tags: java, scala, java-8

I have in my project an Akka layer which returns a `Scala Future`, and the part that receives that Future is Java flavour.

People in the team don't know Scala and they would rather use `CompletableFuture` since they know the Java 8 API much better.

Is there any good way to transform a `Scala future` into a `CompletableFuture`?.

Obviously in a non-blocking way.

Regards.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [scala-java8-compat](https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat) library:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.compat.java8.FutureConverters._

val scalaFuture = Future.apply("Hello")
val javaFuture: CompletableFuture[String] = scalaFuture.toJava.toCompletableFuture
```

Comment: Thanks I will take a look, I´m wondering what they do in the toCompletableFuture, and if they dont just make some nasty blocking CompletableFuture.from(Await(future, X duration)) or something like that :)

Comment: I'm not well grounded enough to give my thoughts on Futures, but please be sure to read the documentation for the `toJava` in addition to the `toCompletableFuture`

Comment: Any idea how to use this from Java World?

Comment: @paul the FutureConverters go both ways (Scala -> Java like in answer and also Java -> Scala, assuming you talking about latter). On an applicable Java `Future` call the `.toScala` while you have the import available and experiment with what methods you can chain on your newly converted `Future`

Comment: yep I already figure, was a problem with Java 9 that does not work the library Thanks!

Comment: Yep - as you can see in the library name `java8-compat` :)

Comment: Since Scala and Java don't have full interoperability (like in Kotlin for example), we need these kinds of library to go from one to another when dealing with complex types and data structures. Maybe when Java 9 is a bit more established the folks at the Scala Center will make a java9-compat library. Or if you're feeling eager you can start working on it yourself :)

Comment: I´m not yet using 9 in production, just in the playground. Once that 9 is production ready, I will fork the project and I will adapt it if we need it.